Resized image looping
I'm trying to add a dynamically resizable logo (PNG image) to my customtkinter window. But it's going in a loop and it doesn't work.
# window
app = ctk.CTk()
app.title("OmniMatrix 3000")
app.geometry("800x500")

# Starting mesure
last_width = 800
last_height = 500

# Logo resize func
def resize_image(event):
    global last_width, last_height
    
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height // 4  # Yüksekliği pencerenin 1/4'ü olarak ayarladım

    image = Image.open("testsurum/logo.png")
    resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    logo_label.configure(image=photo)
    logo_label.image = photo

# First logo upload
image = Image.open("testsurum/logo.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
logo_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text="", image=photo)
logo_label.pack(pady=10)

# resize
app.bind("<Configure>", resize_image)


It is happening because the <Configure> event is triggered every time the window is resized, including your logo.
Add a condition to check if the window size has actually changed before resizing the logo:
def resize_image(event):
    global last_width, last_height
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height // 4
    if new_width != last_width or new_height != last_height:
        last_width = new_width
        last_height = new_height
        image = Image.open("testsurum/logo.png")
        resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
        logo_label.configure(image=photo)
        logo_label.image = photo


its doesnt work... its going to loop again. i am suspicious about my endcode i am using app.loop() at end is it matter for this code?
